# Prove optimality of algorithm

Tags: algorithms

There are $n$ stations($s_1, ..., s_n$) and one can travel a maximum distance of $C$ per day and is only allowed to stop on a station. How much should one travel to finish for the minimum number of days possible? 
 How to prove by contradiction that travelling as much as possible, every day, is an optimal algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Does it have to be a proof by contradiction?  Induction on the minimum number of days to necessary complete the trip is the argument that suggests itself to me.

Comment: What does it mean to "finish"? To visit each station? To get to station $s_n$ from station $s_1$? I am not understanding your question.